# GitLab CI docker build failed

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I want to create a CI pipeline on GitLab for my project.

And I have created two branches: my-server, my-client

My project folder structure is like this below:

```
ROOT:
.gitlab-ci.yml

backend/
--server.js
--Dockerfile
...

react-app/
--some src files...
--Dockerfile
```

And my .gitlab-ci.yml like this:

```
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

variables:
  CONTAINER_IMAGE: myusername/${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}:${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}

docker_build:
  image: docker:stable

  services:
    - docker:dind

  stage: build

  only:
    - my-server
    - my-client

  script:
    - docker login -u ${DOCKER_USERNAME} -p ${DOCKER_PASSWORD}
    - docker build -t ${CONTAINER_IMAGE} .
    - docker push ${CONTAINER_IMAGE}
```

However, the CI job is failed:

```
$ docker build -t ${CONTAINER_IMAGE} .
unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /builds/myusername/my-project/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
```

I don't know how to locate the pipeline to the relative folder (backend and react-app) for building the Dockerfile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the looks of it your DockerFile will be residing inside backend/ and react-app/.

So gitlab CI tries to find the DockerFile in root folder so kindly do

```
cd backend/
cd react-app/
```

in your first cmd of your script section

```
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

variables:   
  CONTAINER_IMAGE: myusername/${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}:${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}

docker_build:
  image: docker:stable

  services:
    - docker:dind

  stage: build

  only:
    - my-server
    - my-client

  script:
    - cd ${DOCKERFILE_PATH} #for backend project and cd react-app/ for frontend
    - docker login -u ${DOCKER_USERNAME} -p ${DOCKER_PASSWORD}
    - docker build -t ${CONTAINER_IMAGE} .
    - docker push ${CONTAINER_IMAGE}
```

Comment: Thanks! I can build the my backend now. As you mentioned cd backend and react-app, I must separate to two .gitlab-ci.yml files? Cannot be done in single file?

Comment: It can be done in a single .gitlab-ci.yml file keep the folder path as some PATH env variable and set them at each project level env varibles. I've edited my answer for your help. so that you need to set the DOCKERFILE_PATH in each project. it'll work accordingly

Comment: Thanks! I modified the yml file for both docker build. I can build and push for server, but there is an error "Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device" while doing the my-client branch pipeline.

Comment: you might've set docker creds as protected variables but my-client-branch might be non-protected branch hence they might prompt for a CLI input